# Scroll to random class with name "foo"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have done this with divs. That i title like this

```
<div id="foo"></div>
<div id="foo2"></div>
<div id="foo3"></div>
<div id="foo4"></div>
<a class="bar">go to random div</a>
```

and then using the jquery I go to a random div id.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Create an array of links
    $("a.bar")
    foo = new Array;
    foo[0] = "#foo";
    foo[1] = "#foo2";
    foo[2] = "#foo3";
    foo[3] = "#foo4";

$("a.bar").click(function() {
        randomLink = Math.round(Math.random() * (foo.length - 1));
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: $(foo[randomLink]).offset().top + "px"
        }, {
            duration: 7000,
            easing: "easeInOutExpo"
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

I am wanting to now do the equivalent but with one class. So an example HTML code would be:

```
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
<a class="bar">go to random class</a>
```

How would I do the equivelant jquery for this situation bearing in mind there is a varied amount of `<div class="foo"></div>` ?

---

### The problem.

I dont know how to create the equivalent array for each class (instead of each div)... Because they are the same...

Any ideas?

Comment: please create jsfiddle for your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with `.eq()` function,

```
var foo = $('.foo');  //Grab all the elements with the class foo

$("a.bar").click(function() {
        randomLink = Math.round(Math.random() * (foo.length - 1));
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: foo.eq(randomLink).offset().top + "px"  
               //pass the random no to .eq() called over .foo collection
        }, {
            duration: 7000,
            easing: "easeInOutExpo"
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

```
$("a.bar").click(function() {

        randomLink = Math.round(Math.random() * (foo.length - 1));
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: $('.foo:eq('+ randomLink +')').offset().top + "px"  
        }, {
            duration: 7000,
            easing: "easeInOutExpo"
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```